# java.lang.RuntimeException: database open failed in Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am new to Android App Development. I was learning about Sqlite and faced a problem. 
I am trying to retrieve data from SQLite Database using Room and found out that "Database open failed" error. The logcat says:

```
2018-10-30 11:30:18.261 2615-2629/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: database open failed
    at com.cleanmaster.provider.DatebaseProvider.a(DatebaseProvider.java:357)
    at com.cleanmaster.provider.DatebaseProvider.query(DatebaseProvider.java:297)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1028)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:567)
```

My AppDatabase.class

```js
package com.impresscapital.iclapp.database;


import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverter;
import android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.impresscapital.iclapp.dao.UserDao;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.dbobj.User;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.util.DateConverter;

@Database(entities = {User.class},version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String LOG_CAT=AppDatabase.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final Object LOCK=new Object();
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="db_icl_app";
    private static AppDatabase sInstance;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if(sInstance==null){
            synchronized (LOCK){
                Log.d(LOG_CAT,"Creating new Database");
                sInstance=Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        AppDatabase.class,AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).build();

            }

        }
        Log.d(LOG_CAT,"Getting the database instance");
        return sInstance;
    }

    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

The class from where I want to access the database is UserSigninAuthentication.class. Here's the code

```js
package com.impresscapital.iclapp.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.impresscapital.iclapp.database.AppDatabase;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.database.AppExecutors;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.dbobj.User;

import java.util.List;

public class UserSigninAuthentication {

    private Boolean isAuthenticate=false;

    public boolean authenticate(final String username, final String password, Context context, final AppDatabase mDb){
        AppExecutors.getsInstance().getDiskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<User> user=mDb.userDao().loadUser(username,password);
                if(user.size()==1){
                    isAuthenticate=true;
                }
                Log.d("IsAuthenticate Value",isAuthenticate.toString());
            }
        });
        return isAuthenticate;
    }



}
```

UserDao.class

```js
package com.impresscapital.iclapp.dao;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Update;

import com.impresscapital.iclapp.dbobj.User;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface UserDao {


    @Query("Select * from user_table where username like :inputUserame and password like :inputPassword LIMIT 1")
    List<User> loadUser(String inputUserame,String inputPassword);

    @Query("Select * from user_table")
    List<User> retrieveAllUser();
    @Insert
    void registerUser(User user);

    @Update
    void updateUser(User user);

    @Delete
    void deleteUser(User user);
}
```

One Important point to be added. I am debugging the app. the execute function of following line is not being executed.

```
AppExecutors.getsInstance().getDiskIO().execute(new Runnable() {..
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out in advance.

Comment: try to change `synchronized (LOCK)` to `synchronized (AppDatabase.class)`

Comment: Are you implementing IPC on your app?

Comment: @AliAhmed it did not work

Comment: @RaymondArteaga No, I am not implementing IPC